# JavaScript - how to make form String to Array?

Tags: javascript

I have data   `const { data: communityData } = useQuery(SEE_ALL_COMMUNITIES_QUERY);`

communtyData is Array and it has field named communityName.

if I console.log `communityData.communityName[0]` then '**abs**' comes.

I need to make array looks like below with this '**abs**'

```
 [
   { label: "abs", value: "abs" },
   { label: "gsd", value: "gsd" },
 ]
```

So I use map function.

```
  const communityNameList = communityData.seeAllCommunities.map(
    (community, index) =>
      `label:${community.communityName}, value:${community.communityName} }`
  );
```

I console.log `communityNameList`,

```
 Array [
  "{ label:abs, value:abs }",
]
```

As you can see it has `"` front and behind the each object.
And I dont' know how to put `"` besides abs.

Please help me

Comment: why didn't you create the object first and then serialized to json string with `JSON.stringify()`? by the way to escape the `"` inside a double quoted string literal you have to use `\"`. But since you are building the string with a template literal, you can just use plain double quotes without escaping it. Just put them around the variable you are echoing in the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to turn this into an Array but into JSON specifically if you want to get the effect you wrote the map should look like this

```
const communityNameList = arr.map((community, index) => {
    return {
        "label": community.communityName,
        "value": community.communityName
    };
});
```

Comment: there was a simple way 

Comment: Using some syntactic sugar including parameter destructuring and the arrow function syntax from **nem0z**' answer, the mapping function *could* be rewritten more compactly (just a preference, sometimes more readable) as ...`.map(({communityName: n}) => ({ label: n, value: n }));` The `index` parameter is not used and so not needed.

Comment: I wrote it more on the basis of the author's code where the index occurs, I was aware that it is not needed, but since it is there, he will probably want to use it for something well I gave him a more pleasant example of code to edit if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
const communityNameList = communityData.seeAllCommunities.map(community => ({
        label: community.communityName, 
        value: community.communityName 
    })
);
```

Note : When you want to return JSON from arrow function you have to surround the return statement with ()